# Short Url with FlexiContent Or Remove menu item alias from URL

Tags: joomla-4.x, sef, flexicontent

I am using flexicontent for content management in Joomla 4.3.4.
And i created the Menu as

> All content->Edited->News

As its URL with menu item alias

> my-domain/all-content/edited/news/content-title

one home page it create short url like

> my-domain/content-title

but in other pages it creates url on items link

> my-domain/all-content/edited/news/item-title

I tried to make this changes with code customization but no success.
and also i used 4SEF but can not make short urls.
Am i looking at wrong way?

Comment: If you look at other recent questions on this forum you'll see that other people are having issues with the SEF URLs that the Joomla router is generating!